# How can I join three tables in MS Access SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a simple table model with 3 tables but I am not able to join them in the way I need it.

```
Table: TOPIC
ID  TITLE
1   Talk1
2   Talk2
3   Talk3
4   Talk4

Table: SPEAKER
ID   NAME
20   Speaker20
21   Speaker21
22   Speaker22
23   Speaker23

Table: CONNECTOR
ID_TOPIC  ID_SPEAKER
1         21
2         23
2         22
2         21
4         20
4         22
```

In Table CONNECTOR the Topics are getting assigned to speakers.
One Topic can be assigned to different speakers.
There can also be topics in the TOPIC table which are not assigned yet, like in this example topic 3.
What I need is an SQL which give me as result all topics from the TOPICS table with the assigned speakers with name but I also want the topics in the result list which are not assigned through the CONNECTOR table.
How should the join look like to get this result?

Comment: *There can also be topics in the TOPIC table which are not assigned yet, like in this example topic 3.* But what about SPEAKER?

Comment: At the moment there can't be speaker which have no at leat one assigned topic. But there will be a new column in the SPEAKER table which shows if the speaker is inactiv.

Comment: You guarantee this will not occur in future? if not it is better to consider this possibility now than to update urgently in the future.

Comment: For the report which is based on this SQL I need a list of all Topics and an counter which shows how many assignment of Speaker each Topic has. So I was thinking just to group the result of this SQL by the Topic Name or Topic ID directly in the report. But of course maybe for another Report I have to consider your solution. By the way do you know if it is possible to do this grouping with counter directly in the SQL?

Comment: What is the reason to ask one while needed another? *For the report which is based on this SQL I need a list of all Topics and an counter which shows how many assignment of Speaker each Topic has.* Use **Foxfire**'s solution with proper grouping and counting if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did an example in Access and got this:

[image]

As you can see, the query lists all topics, even if there is no speaker assigned. The SQL code of my query is this:

```
SELECT TOPICS.Title, SPEAKER.SpeakerName
FROM SPEAKER RIGHT JOIN (CONNECTOR RIGHT JOIN TOPICS ON CONNECTOR.ID_TOPIC = TOPICS.Id) ON SPEAKER.ID = CONNECTOR.ID_SPEAKER;
```

Hope this helps

**UPDATE:** Please, note that in table SPEAKERS, I've used as fieldname `SpeakerName` instead of `Name` because `Name` it's a reserved word, and it can create some troubles using it.

Answer (score 0):

Look for

```
SELECT TOPIC.TITLE, SPEAKER.NAME
FROM ( CONNECTOR 
       INNER JOIN TOPIC ON TOPIC.ID = CONNECTOR.ID_TOPIC) 
     INNER JOIN SPEAKER ON CONNECTOR.ID_SPEAKER = SPEAKER.ID
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, SPEAKER.NAME
FROM SPEAKER 
LEFT JOIN CONNECTOR ON CONNECTOR.ID_SPEAKER = SPEAKER.ID
WHERE CONNECTOR.ID_TOPIC Is Null
UNION ALL
SELECT TOPIC.TITLE, NULL
FROM TOPIC 
LEFT JOIN CONNECTOR ON TOPIC.ID = CONNECTOR.ID_TOPIC
WHERE CONNECTOR.ID_TOPIC Is Null;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But is it not more effective to do it with Right join like in @Foxfire And Burns And Burns solution?

Comment: @Artie200 No way to show both Topics and Speakers not mentioned in Connector at the same time ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w97j.png)) using the solution similar to one provided by ***Foxfire And Burns And Burns***. Only either Topics or Speakers. If it is enough for you - use his solution.

Comment: @ Akina Ok I understand. Really good hint. Thanks a lot again.